# Is there websites where I can get XCF resources for GIMP (similar to PSDKey for photoshop resources)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

There are a lot of websites which are dedicated to graphic designers and photo editors who are using Adobe Photoshop. I am currently exploring alternatives and GIMP seems like a good option. But I used to be very reliant on resources from PSDkeys, Freepik and so on. I was wondering if there is any website that has a collection of resources to be used in GIMP.

Comment: There are not many programs which support non-destructive adjustments, effects and geometric distortion filters. Photoshop has supported it over a decade and that has made possible the whole business of "insert your own artwork" templates. Web service Photopea supports them  and it opens also template PSDs. I have tried only simple ones which use only RGB and do not have many layers, groups nor effects. GIMP doesn't support non-destructivity at all except layer masks. Affinity Photo ver.2 has a big collection of non destructive modifiers, but the product has been available only one year.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any stock image sites that offer native GIMP XCF files, probably because Photoshop doesn't support the format at all. However most existing stock image sites have a plethora of images in other formats that GIMP can open.

If you are reliant on PSD mockups which use smart objects or layer styles, then these won't open properly in GIMP. It doesn't support those features. However GIMP can open basic layered PSDs, and many other image formats such as PNG, TIFF, JPEG, even SVG (which will be rasterized). If you are working with SVG or vectors generally, better to use Inkscape which is a free and open source vector image editor.

A possible option for you to open PSD mockups with smart objects and layer styles is the online editor Photopea which does support these features - although I'm not entirely sure it is 100% compatible with all Photoshop PSDs. I can't really vouch for this online editor as I've never needed to use it for any actual work. I've only played around with it.